# Vanilla Javascript ES6 equivalent of jQuery toggle()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

This jQuery `toggle()` function is working great. What is good practice for doing the same in vanilla javascript (ES6 preferred)?

```
$("#sign_up_btn").click(function(e) {
    $(signUpForm).toggle("hide");
    $(loginForm).toggle("hide");
});

$("#login_btn").click(function(e) {
    $(signUpForm).toggle("hide");
    $(loginForm).toggle("hide");
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Native Toggle

Class can be toggled natively via [`Element.classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Examples):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#sign_up_btn');
button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('.content').classList.toggle('hide')
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="sign_up_btn">toggle</button>

<div class="content">Toggle this content</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

**Note:** the CSS is just so we can test here.

```js
document.getElementById('sign_up_btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var signUpForm = document.getElementById('signUpForm');
  var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
  
  if(window.getComputedStyle(signUpForm).display === "block") {
    signUpForm.style.display = "none";
    loginForm.style.display = "block";   
  } else {
    signUpForm.style.display = "block";
    loginForm.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#signUpForm {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #09f;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#loginForm {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

#sign_up_btn {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="sign_up_btn" value="Sign up" />

<div id="signUpForm">Sign up form</div>
<div id="loginForm">Log in form</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way.

```js
var show = function (elem) {
 elem.style.display = 'block';
};

var hide = function (elem) {
 elem.style.display = 'none';
};

var toggle = function (elem) {

 // If the element is visible, hide it
 if (window.getComputedStyle(elem).display === 'block') {
  hide(elem);
  return;
 }

 // Otherwise, show it
 show(elem);

};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

 // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
 if (!event.target.classList.contains('toggle')) return;

 // Prevent default link behavior
 event.preventDefault();

 // Get the content
 var content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
 if (!content) return;

 // Toggle the content
 toggle(content);

}, false);
```

```html
<p>
  <a class="toggle" href="#example">Toggle Div</a>
</p>

<div class="toggle-content" id="example">
  Here's some text we want to toggle visibility of. Let's do it!
</div>
```

Comment: Font:
https://gomakethings.com/how-to-show-and-hide-elements-with-vanilla-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

If *signUpForm* and *loginForm* are ids then you can try the following:

```
document.getElementById('sign_up_btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  elToggle();
});

document.getElementById('login_btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  elToggle();
});

function elToggle(){
  var s = document.getElementById('signUpForm');
  if (s.style.display == "none") {
    s.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    s.style.display = "none";
  }

  var l = document.getElementById('loginForm');
  if (l.style.display == "none") {
    l.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    l.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```